# Multiple background color for div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div`

```
<div class="test">
   Some text
</div>
```

I would like to have different *background color* for the same `div` by *percent* (Horizontal coloring)

```
-----------------------------
| 20%   |  30%   | 50%      |
| Red   | Yellow | Green    |
-----------------------------
```

Is this possible with CSS?

Comment: Do you want a gradient or strictly limited color areas?

Answer (score 12):

You can use CSS3 Gradients<sup>[1]</sup> to achieve such effect

```
div {
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #ff3236 0%,#ff3033 32%,#3e30ff 32%,#3e30ff 63%,#33ff30 63%,#33ff30 100%);
    height: 400px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JvQJv/)

You can create such gradients over [here](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

---

You can also use `px` as a unit, along with `%` if you are looking for static gradient widths

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JvQJv/2/) <sup>(Please add `browser-prefixes` if you are looking for a cross browser solution, I've not added all the rules in this demo)</sup>

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/JvQJv/7/) *(Vertical Split, just change `to right` to `to bottom`)*

<sup>1. [More on CSS3 Gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_gradients)</sup>      
<sup>2. [Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/css-gradients)</sup>

Comment: what CSS3 generator are you using ?

Comment: @Mohsen Just shared :)

Comment: Thanks :), I used it before but not like this

Comment: @Mohsen crazy techniques you see ;)

Comment: Thanks  didn't appreciate linear-gradient could be used in this way.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this by using a gradient:

Either google it and create an own.
Or use a generator like this:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

which gives you the following css-code:

```
background: #ff3019; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #ff3019 0%, #d40000 20%, #f2f600 20%, #f2f600 50%, #1e7a00 50%, #1e7a00 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ff3019), color-stop(20%,#d40000), color-stop(20%,#f2f600), color-stop(50%,#f2f600), color-stop(50%,#1e7a00), color-stop(100%,#1e7a00)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #ff3019 0%,#d40000 20%,#f2f600 20%,#f2f600 50%,#1e7a00 50%,#1e7a00 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #ff3019 0%,#d40000 20%,#f2f600 20%,#f2f600 50%,#1e7a00 50%,#1e7a00 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #ff3019 0%,#d40000 20%,#f2f600 20%,#f2f600 50%,#1e7a00 50%,#1e7a00 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #ff3019 0%,#d40000 20%,#f2f600 20%,#f2f600 50%,#1e7a00 50%,#1e7a00 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3019', endColorstr='#1e7a00',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create three descendant divs within the parent. Absolutely position them, make the parent transparent, then give the three divs a z-index of 0 so they sit underneath the text, not on top.

Answer (score 1):

This method of progressive enhancement works for all browsers that support CSS 2.1 pseudo-elements and their positioning. No CSS3 support required

```
#div{
   position:relative;
   z-index:1;
   min-width:200px;
   min-height:200px;
   padding:120px 200px 50px;
   background:#d3ff99 url(vines-back.png) -10% 0 repeat-x;
}
#div:before,
#div:after {
   position:absolute;
   z-index:-1;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   padding-top:100px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/)