# how to make a background color using 2 colors CSS3

Tags: css, background, background-color

I want to make a background with 2 colors 1 frame arround white with 2 px height and in the middle grey. for example it will be like a 2 pixels border white and the the rest grey, but I don't want to use border, the background has to make its own border. Is anyone knows how to make it ? any ideas using css3 ?

Thanks.

Comment: You may need this gradient generator, although your question is unclear and I'm not sure what you trying to say, however check this out http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: maybe using also 2 html div, one inside the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple background color for div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068123/multiple-background-color-for-div)

Comment: I want to use only ine div yes I can try with a color gradient to see

Comment: Try to play with this: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#c4c4c4+0,c4c4c4+50,ffffff+51,c4c4c4+52,c4c4c4+100;Custom

Comment: I tryied with the colors gradient and I can only make one border, I want the 4 borders to have a diffrent colors than the main colors

Comment: So please provide what you've done yet. We just can't help without reviewing your code.

Comment: Please provide a picture of what you want.

Comment: You can use `box-shadow` (including `inset`) to emulate multiple borders.

Comment: Why don't you want to use border? If you're concerned about the size of the element being affected, you can use box-sizing: border-box. You can also use the :before and :after elements (again with a border) or box-shadow as @NielsKeurentjes commented.

Comment: Ok thanks I'm gonna try with box shadow